# How to reply an inline keyboard markup in python

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, telethon

I want to implement a python script where I talk to a telegram chatbot using the Telethon library.
At some point in the conversation I have to click an element of the type inline keyboard markup with two choices.
I can't find a function that allows me to click on one of the two options.
Can you advise me?

Comment: Take a look at the `Message` object reference. It has a method to click on buttons https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#message